# Testing against NULL or nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

See this code:

```
if (m_hStatusBarPageBreakIcon != NULL)
    VERIFY(DestroyIcon(m_hStatusBarPageBreakIcon));
```

Sometimes when I have opted to use `nullptr` the compiler complains. But as a general rule is it OK to use `nullptr`? This variable is of type `HICON`.

Comment: What is the message you get from the compiler?

Comment: @NutCracker In this instance I an **not** getting an error. But at other time sfor example I have passed `nullptr` as a parameter (because my intellisense was suggesting I convert to `NULL`. Sorry I can't be specific in this instance. Shall I delete this question and actually ask the next time the compiler fails? Probably better to do that!

Comment: You might want to do that because we can't help you if we don't know the real case and the compiler complain.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using? This should not cause a warning. You share the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Why not just `if (m_hStatusBarPageBreakIcon) ...`?

Comment: Windows is weird. Don't fight its idioms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming compiler supports `nullptr`, the only case where checking a handle for `NULL` works, but for `nullptr` fails to compiler is a case where a handle is not defined as a pointer.

As Windows headers define `NULL` as `0`, the check for `NULL` could work for integer handles, for example. Sure checking an integer for `nullptr` is an error.

For such cases, if some handle is integer, or some API is documented to accept `NULL`, I would still replace `NULL`, not with `nullptr`, but with literal `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I will look on that from a different perspective. Basically I want to have typesafe code. 
`NULL` is even better than `nullptr`, because 0 is of type int and `nullptr` is anything.

And static code analysis tools will emit an information if you write `uint i=3U`, then some more code and then `if (i == 0)`. Same with `NULL` and `nullptr`.

So, what I use is:

```
template <typename T>
const T null(void) 
{
    return static_cast<T>(0);
}
```

Example code

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
. . . 
uchar someVariable = null<uchar>();
SomeComplexClass *someComplexClass = null<SomeComplexClass *>();
. . . 
if (null<SomeComplexClass *>() == someComplexClass)
{
    . . . 
}
```

The normal programmer will sit there and say. What is that nonsense?

But consider, we develop some ASIL D code. And then you refactor your code. And you will accidently modify "SomeComplexClass" to "someOtherComplexClass".

```
if (null<SomeComplexClass *>() == someOtherComplexClass)
```

With this typesafe 0, the static code analysis tools will emit an info.

Think of that, when you drive your car next time with an ASIL D rated steering-wheel, brake- or accelarator-pedal software.

BTW: also `auto` should be avoided wherever possible in such code.